# Limiting access to Hive Partitions

Tags: hive, partition

I have a Hive table Person with 50 partitions (one for each state). Is there any way I can limit access to the partitions in Hive? For e.g: I want a user to have access to partition CA and IL only, any way to implement this in Hive.

I'm on Hive 0.12 currently

Comment: One of the ways is to use Sentry tool.

Answer (score 0):

Having VIEWS on top of your table with specific grants to the required users is the simplest option.

Comment: I do not think that Hive 0.12 has options to restrict access.